# How to combine constraints

Tags: haskell

I need to write a function that takes in two constraints and returns a third constraint that is satisfied only if the first two are also satisfied. I could write a helper function that tests if the first two constraints return true or false, but the problem is that the test could be anything so I can't just pass in something in order to test it. Is there a way to somehow combine two functions/constraints of any type?

I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you need `(&&)` function. Else I don't understand your question.

Comment: && doesn't work on functions tho.

Comment: What is a constraint? Does it have any type signature? Like `:: a -> Bool`?

Comment: didn't know how, I just upvoted them. I just figured out how to do it, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that by "constraint" you mean some sort of predicate, you can easily write a function which combines two predicates to make a new predicate.

```
type Pred a = a -> Bool

both :: Pred a -> Pred a -> Pred a
both p1 p2 x = p1 x && p2 x
```

A quick test run:

```
*Main Data.Char> both odd (> 3) 5
True
*Main Data.Char> both isAlpha isUpper 'b'
False
```

Comment: that is only assuming that you know the type, but it's actually unknown, could be anything

Comment: I think you'll have to clarify what you mean with an example.

Comment: hmm, that seems to work... I think. But how come it's taking in x as the third perimeter when you only declared two?

Comment: That's because the return type, `Pred a` is a function. I could also have written `both p1 p2 = \x -> ...`, just as I could have written `both p1 = \p2 -> \x -> ...`. Thanks to currying, they're the same thing!

Comment: it needs to return a function, your method returns a bool. how do I write it in a way for it to return a function>?

Comment: It does return a function! Just use partial application and don't give it the "x" argument. For example, `both isAlpha isUpper` is a function of type `Char -> Bool`.

Comment: my code: data Cons a = Con (a -> Bool)
twoCons :: Cons a -> Cons a -> Cons a

Comment: In that case, you'll just need to add some wrapping and unwrapping: `twoCons (Con p1) (Con p2) = Con $ \x -> p1 x && p2 x`. Here I use pattern matching to extract the functions from your data type, then I make the new function using a lambda and wrap it back up using the `Con` data constructor.

Comment: how do you implement two cons? your code by itself works but when I tried to implement it into my code it gives an error, probably because of the data type I have?

Comment: what's this error I'm getting using wrapping and unwrapping? An instance of Show (a -> Bool) is required to derive Show (Cons a)

Comment: Oh and next time, include your code in the question. Don't make us have to guess.

Comment: I added deriving(Eq, Show) after the data type

Comment: You should post that as a separate question.

Comment: ok thanks for all the help so far, I will try to figure it out, and if I can't get it I will post another question.

Answer (score 3):

Obligatory cryptic answer:

```
import Control.Arrow
import Data.Composition

both :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool) -> a -> Bool
both = uncurry (&&) .** (&&&)
```

Someday I'll get around to documenting my Data.Composition library properly ([it's on hackage!](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/composition)), but basically `(.**) f g x y z = f (g x y z)`

Here's how it works (simplified how &&& works on functions)

```
(&&&) f g x = (f x, g x)
uncurry f (x,y) = f x y
(.**) f g x y z = f (g x y z)

both = uncurry (&&) .** (&&&)
-- undo infix notation
both = (.**) (uncurry (&&)) (&&&)
-- definition of .**, with f = (uncurry (&&)), g = (&&&), x = p1, y = p2, z = v
both = \p1 p2 v -> (uncurry (&&)) ((&&&) p1 p2 v) 
-- definition of &&&, with f = p1, g = p2, x = v
both = \p1 p2 v -> (uncurry (&&)) (p1 v, p2 v)
-- definition of uncurry, with f = (&&)
both = \p1 p2 v -> (\(x, y) -> (&&) x y) (p1 v, p2 v)
-- function application, bind x = p1 v, y = pw v
both = \p1 p2 v -> (&&) (p1 v) (p2 v)
-- rewrite without lambda, move && to infix position
both p1 p2 v = p1 v && p2 v
```

We have now arrived at hammar's definition. :)

Comment: That looks needlessly complicated. Doesn't plain old `liftM2 (&&)` work just as well?

Comment: @DanielWagner well sure. But I wanted to play with `(&&&)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two tests of type:

```
constraint1 :: a -> Bool
constraint2 :: b -> Bool
```

And you wish to build a third constriant that is the union of the two, then just use `(&&)`:

```
constraint3 :: a -> b -> Bool
constraint3 a b = constraint1 a && constraint2 b
```